# How to setup Moq for the same method where return value depends on input?

Tags: c#, moq

I'd like to test a method called multiple times during test, in a way where the tested method output depends on its input. I checked Moq's documentation and the following example seems to what I need.

```
// matching Func<int>, lazy evaluated
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Add(It.Is<int>(i => i % 2 == 0))).Returns(true);
```

The tested method looks like this:

```
Task<DimensionStructure> GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(DimensionStructure dimensionStructure);
```

The DimensionStructure class looks like this, it is simplified as on the `Id` is important.

```
public class DimensionStructure
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I put together the mock I need, example below, when it is called it returns always `null`.

```
_masterDataWebApiClientMock.Setup(m => m.GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(
                    It.Is<DimensionStructure>(
                        structure => structure.Id == 101)
                ))
               .ReturnsAsync(addedToRoot);
_masterDataWebApiClientMock.Setup(m => m.GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(
                    It.Is<DimensionStructure>(
                        structure => structure.Id == 201 )
                ))
               .ReturnsAsync(addedToFirstLevel);
```

The point os that the method gets different parameter and returns different objects.
In both cases, it returns `null`. According to the doc, it should return what is in the `ReturnAsync` which is not null.

It works perfectly in another test where the `Id` property value of the object doesn't matter.

```
_masterDataWebApiClientMock.Setup(m => m.GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(It.IsAny<DimensionStructure>()))
               .ReturnsAsync(addedDimensionStructure);
```

The question is, how to solve this?

**Update - 02/29/2020**

When I do not specify the call parameter then it is just working fine. It makes a bit tricky to test the method, but solvable.

```
_masterDataWebApiClientMock
               .Setup(m => m.GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(
                    It.IsAny<DimensionStructure>()
                ))
               .ReturnsAsync(addedToRoot);
```

On the other hand I [reported](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/973) this case a special, possible bug case to Moq folks.

Answer (score 2):

Having put together a test bench as follows I can see it returns correct values.
It seems either my assumptions about `IClassUnderTest` are wrong or you might need to ensure `addedToRoot` and `addedToFirstLevel` are defined **when you call your mocked method**.

This probably doesn't answer your question per se, I'm however hoping this will either point you in the right direction or will prompt for more information.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq; //I'm running Moq 4.13 

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public class DimensionStructure
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
        Task<DimensionStructure> GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(DimensionStructure dimensionStructure);
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var addedToRoot = new DimensionStructure { Id = 1 };
            var addedToFirstLevel = new DimensionStructure { Id = 2 };

            var _masterDataWebApiClientMock = new Mock<ITest>();
            _masterDataWebApiClientMock.Setup(m => m.GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(
                    It.Is<DimensionStructure>(
                        structure => structure.Id == 101)
                ))
                .ReturnsAsync(addedToRoot);
            _masterDataWebApiClientMock.Setup(m => m.GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(
                    It.Is<DimensionStructure>(
                        structure => structure.Id == 201)
                ))
                .ReturnsAsync(addedToFirstLevel);


            Assert.AreEqual(1, _masterDataWebApiClientMock.Object.GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(new DimensionStructure { Id = 101 }).Result.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, _masterDataWebApiClientMock.Object.GetDimensionStructureByIdAsync(new DimensionStructure { Id = 201 }).Result.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In one hand, it helps a lot because it shows that I followed the good pattern, but, on the other hand, shows that either I made a small mistake somewhere in my code, or I messed up really something and I haven't realized yet. :) I need to take a long sleep and take a look at the code with fresh eyes and thoughts tomorrow. Thanks again! :)